# XCode Upload Hangs when a certain SDK is included

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, organizer

This is the weirdest problem that I have ever encountered in XCode.

Recently I wanted to add a certain SDK to my app. I'm not going to name
this SDK because I don't want to discredit their name. Anyway, the strange
thing is that whenever I included the SDK into my app, while it can work
ok in the app, during upload (after validate success), the uploader just
hangs there and not uploading any data at all for a long time (i waited about
10minutes). No progress whatsoever.

Then I removed the SDK, and commented out the related SDK codes (just delegates),
I was able to upload fine. Then just for sure, I added back the SDK and implemented
the SDK codes, again, archive the app, validate, and try to upload, it just stuck
there again.

Anybody have any idea why is this so?

It is so annoying. Organizer did not give any message either.

Comment: Have you tried if `Save for Enterprise Deployment` works instead of `Submit to the AppStore`?

Comment: Yes, Save for Enterprise Distribution works OK. It saved an .ipa file on my desktop.

Comment: Btw, I've also asked this to the SDK owner. In the meantime if anyone has any clue, pls help. Thanks.